# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3_Other'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

I have a dataset and I want to convert all data types to an integer. one of the datatypes of the column is an object and the value in it is like"3_other", "3_server".
how can I convert "3_other" to integer in pandas?

the column name is: "label_poly"

label_poly:
3_other
3_server
3_samba

Comment: How can you convert ```3_other``` to an Integer? Perhaps you mean ```3``` or the number in it?

Comment: i want convert all "3_other" , "3_server" convert to integer . every of them are three-label class